# maven-dependency-plugin unpack of large file size issue

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

The maven build is failing when the maven-dependency-plugin is trying to unpack because of the file being larger than 4gb.

Is there an option or configuration to fix this?

One could easily reproduce this problem by trying to instantiate ZipFile with a file that is bigger than 4gb

```
        org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile zip = new org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile(
                new File("<file-path"));

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
            <version>1.20</version>
        </dependency>
```

```
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.populateFromCentralDirectory (ZipFile.java:709)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.<init> (ZipFile.java:371)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.<init> (ZipFile.java:256)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.<init> (ZipFile.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.AbstractZipUnArchiver.execute (AbstractZipUnArchiver.java:201)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.AbstractZipUnArchiver.execute (AbstractZipUnArchiver.java:180)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractUnArchiver.extract (AbstractUnArchiver.java:149)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.AbstractDependencyMojo.unpack (AbstractDependencyMojo.java:313)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.AbstractDependencyMojo.unpack (AbstractDependencyMojo.java:224)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.fromDependencies.UnpackDependenciesMojo.doExecute (UnpackDependenciesMojo.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.AbstractDependencyMojo.execute (AbstractDependencyMojo.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call (MultiThreadedBuilder.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call (MultiThreadedBuilder.java:198)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Which version of maven-dependency plugin are you using? Apart from why are you using the dependency plugin to upack a file?

Comment: I am using 3.1.2 version.

Comment: One could easily reproduce this problem by trying to instantiate ZipFile with a file that is bigger than 4gb

  org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile zip = new org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile(
    new File("<file-path"));

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
   <version>1.20</version>
  </dependency>